# image-magic: select orientation of the stacked image

Tags: imagemagick

I am using montage of imagemagic to stack horizontally 3 types of image producing Nx3 table:

```
montage \( "${output}/type1*.png" \) \( "${output}/type2*.png" \) \( "${output}/type3*.png" \) -geometry 800x600+1+1 -frame 4 -background white -mattecolor lightgoldenrod2 -mode Frame -bordercolor white ${output}/summary.png
```

is it possible to add here some option in order to produce vertically-stacked table of the Nx3 elements. I found only a possibility to do it via
convert where I need to specify -apend option:

```
convert \( "${output}/type1*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) \( "${output}/type2*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) \( "${output}/type3*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 2x0 +append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/summary.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Imagemagick by transposing all your images, do the montage, then transpose the result using pipes between convert and montage and convert.

```
convert lena.jpg mandril3.jpg zelda1.jpg redhat.jpg -transpose miff:- | montage - -tile 2x2 miff:- | convert - -transpose result.png
```

[image]